# Material UI stop Flexbox on small screen

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

Is it possible to stop *Flexbox* on small screen with Material UI?
I need somethings like *d-md-flex* class in Bootstrap but using Material UI.

Bootstrap (works as expected)

```
<div class="d-md-flex align-items-md-center">
    <div>Content #1</div>
    <div>Content #2</div>
</div>
```

React:

```
<Box container display="flex">
    <Box item>Content #1</Box>
    <Box item>Content #2</Box>
</Box>
```

Elements should be placed close together on large screen, and one above the other on small screens.

Any inputs are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do... you can achieve it with media queries, for example like that:

```js
import { useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import useMediaQuery from '@material-ui/core/useMediaQuery';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

const someComponent = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

  return (
    <Container maxWidth="md">
      <Box container display={isMobile ? 'block' : 'flex'}>
        <Box item>Content #1</Box>
        <Box item>Content #2</Box>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: Super! That's what I meant. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer.
Unfortunately using Grid it is not possible to have the columns completely close together (due to the size of the column). I'm looking for the same behavior but using the Box element which keeps the child elements close together. Thanks for your inputs.